# InStr is not finding the substring/Is it searching the whole string?

Tags: excel, vba, variant, instr

InStr code and value. We are looking for "M" in StndMCardIndic. StndMCardIndic is "S(16B,17B)|M(18B)|IO(19B)".

[image]

As you can see I am searching StndMCardIndic for the character "M". The value of StndMCardIndic is `"S(16B,17B)|M(18B)|IO(19B)"`. A `"M"` is clearly present. However, it fails to find it. I suspect this is due to the length of the string. If so, how would I find it?

Comment: Change the `= 1` to `> 0`.

Comment: ^^^^^^Instr returns the relative location of the match and 0 if not found.  By using `=1` you are only testing if the string starts with `M`

Comment: @BigBen I see it now. Thanks. Not sure why I thought it was a true(1) or false(0) return.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see it. Thanks!

Comment: A good start would be the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function), which would immediately refute your assumption. Also, why would you use `= 1` if it returned a `Boolean`?